# Mixed targets in VSTS build

Tags: continuous-integration, .net-core, azure-devops, .net-4.6

We have an `aspnet-core` application which consists of several `.net standard` libraries, two `aspnet-core mvc` applications and, exceptionally, a `.net framework` console application.

These all build successfully, both in solution in Visual Studio, and also individually using `msbuild`/`dotnet build` commands.

We are now trying to implement continuous integration/build with VSTS.

We have found that the `aspnet-core` web applications build successfully, but the `.net framework` console application fails with multiple error messages like the following:

```
2017-12-24T07:20:26.4090447Z C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1988,5): 
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the 
assembly "Xxx.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. 
If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. 
[d:\a\1\s\WinApps\ListBuilder\ListBuilder.csproj]
```

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\WinApps\TelemListBuilder\TelemListBuilder.csproj]
```

The console application follows the same folder structure as the web applications but seems unable to find any of the referenced packages.

Our Agent queue is `Hosted VS2017`.

We have two VSTS tasks: `Restore` and `Build` from the `asp.net core` build template.

If necessary we would be happy if we could exclude the console app from the build.

Comment: Is the restore task a .net core restore task or a "normal" NuGet restore task?

Comment: They are the `dotnet core` tasks from the `asp.net core` build template.  We will try adding the "normal" nuget restore task. Would you expect the `dotnet core` build task to work with the framework console app?

Comment: Yes it has support for packages.config which isn’t present in the core tools

Comment: Also use visual studio build for the classic project

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to try any of these yet. I will update when I find the time.

Comment: Yes this did the trick! I have accepted your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are general .net framework project and .net core project and you want to build them together, you need to use **Visual Studio Build task**.

So, remove **.Net Core Restore** and **.Net Core build tasks** and add N**uGet Tool Installer (4.3.0)**, **Nuget restore** and **Visual Studio Build** tasks (Visual Studio Version: Latest or Visual Studio 2017)

If you want to generate the deployment package during the build, you can specify MSBuild arguments like this:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
```